Did Jesus the Christ practise Judaism?
I read the following on the internet:

Jesus continued practicing Judaism, per Luke 4:16 ("as his custom was, he went into the synagogue on the sabbath day, and stood up for to read").
The Pharisees criticized Jesus because they (incorrectly) thought he violated God's commandments, something they wouldn't have cared about if he hadn't been Jewish.

Luke 4:16 says:

He went to Nazareth, where he had been brought up, and on the Sabbath day he went into the synagogue, as was his custom. He stood up to read,  and the scroll of the prophet Isaiah was handed to him. Unrolling it, he found the place where it is written:
"The Spirit of the Lord is on me, because he has anointed me to proclaim good news to the poor. He has sent me to proclaim freedom for the prisoners and recovery of sight for the blind, to set the oppressed free, to proclaim the year of the Lord’s favor.”
Then he rolled up the scroll, gave it back to the attendant and sat down. The eyes of everyone in the synagogue were fastened on him. He began by saying to them, “Today this scripture is fulfilled in your hearing.”
All spoke well of him and were amazed at the gracious words that came from his lips. “Isn’t this Joseph’s son?” they asked.
Jesus said to them, “Surely you will quote this proverb to me: ‘Physician, heal yourself!’ And you will tell me, ‘Do here in your hometown what we have heard that you did in Capernaum.’”
“Truly I tell you,” he continued, “no prophet is accepted in his hometown. I assure you that there were many widows in Israel in Elijah’s time, when the sky was shut for three and a half years and there was a severe famine throughout the land. Yet Elijah was not sent to any of them, but to a widow in Zarephath in the region of Sidon [in Lebanon]. And there were many in Israel with leprosy in the time of Elisha the prophet, yet not one of them was cleansed—only Naaman the Syrian.”
All the people in the synagogue were furious when they heard this. They got up, drove him out of the town, and took him to the brow of the hill on which the town was built, in order to throw him off the cliff.  But he walked right through the crowd and went on his way.

As reported, above, Jesus speaks from Isaiah. The Isaiah passage continues to say:

They will rebuild the ancient ruins and restore the places long devastated; they will renew the ruined cities that have been devastated for generations.  Strangers will shepherd your flocks; foreigners will work your fields and vineyards.  And you will be called priests of the Lord, you will be named ministers of our God. You will feed on the wealth of nations, and in their riches you will boast. Instead of your shame you will receive a double portion, and instead of disgrace you will rejoice in your inheritance. And so you will inherit a double portion in your land, and everlasting joy will be yours. In my faithfulness I will reward my people and make an everlasting covenant with them.  Their descendants will be known among the nations and their offspring among the peoples. All who see them will acknowledge that they are a people the Lord has blessed
I have posted watchmen on your walls, Jerusalem; they will never be silent day or night. You who call on the Lord, give yourselves no rest,  and give him no rest till he establishes Jerusalem and makes her the praise of the earth.
The Lord has sworn by his right hand and by his mighty arm: “Never again will I give your grain as food for your enemies, and never again will foreigners drink the new wine for which you have toiled;  but those who harvest it will eat it and praise the Lord, and those who gather the grapes will drink it in the courts of my sanctuary.”

Jesus later did not appear to teach what Isaiah taught. In fact, the very opposite, for example, Jesus's ministry did not appear concerned with accruing worldly material wealth (Matthew 6:24); Jesus appeared to prophesize the destruction of The Temple & the towns (Mark 13:1-3); and Jesus appeared to deemphasize Jewish tribal identity (Luke 10:25-37; Colossians 3:11-13).
Is/was it the "practice of Judaism" to publicly claim you are a special anointed Prophet, to quote the Jewish prophets out of context, to praise Gentiles in Lebanon and Syria, and to make the Jewish congregation so angry to throw you off a cliff?

This question is similar to: Did Jesus himself assert the fact that he belonged to some religion like Judaism?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

My question is more specific than the general question asked in 2013. The purpose of my question is particularly to gain clarity on Luke 4:16.

The questions seem off, in that certain assumptions/views are applied and questions are based on this perspective without backing. was/is it practice of Judaism to claim you are special anointed prophet....no, but Jesus was special, anointed. quote out of context....no, but was it?

No, Jesus did not practise Judaism. According to the New Testament, Jesus practised Christianity. And Judaism and Christianity are two different religions. Jesus clearly teached the beginning of a new religion/covenant.
Some would now argue: "But Jesus was circumcised, visited Synagogues and celebrated Jewish feasts" Yes, he was circumcised, but did he decide it for himself? No, his parents did. Yes, he visited Synagogues, but for what purpose? To convince the Jews there to become Christians. Even the Christian apostle Paul visited Synagogues, not because he practised Judaism, but to convince the Jews for Christianity. Also, when Jesus visited Synagogues and preached there, the Jews tried to kill him. This means Jesus preached not Judaism, otherwise they wouldn't try to kill him. And yes, he celebrated Jewish feasts, but for what purpose? To use these feasts as foreshadows for the new religion - Christianity. Jesus used the Jewish feasts to show his disciples that these feasts are just prophecies of his own person. For example, when celebrated the passover, he said that the bread and the wine are meant to be his body and blood which will be sacrificed. And the apostle Paul said that the passover lamb represents Jesus. So Jesus didn't celebrate the feasts in the same way like Judaism does.
Everyone who has read the whole New Testament comes to the conclusion that Jesus' religion was Christianity, not Judaism. In fact, Jesus was an Anti-Judaist. He attacked the Pharisees who are praised as the fathers of Judaism. The Pharisees were the highest scholars, they wrote the Talmud. The Talmud is the central text of Judaism, because the Talmud is the way how Jews interpret the Old Testament. So if you attack the Pharisees, you basically attack Judaism, and Jesus attacked the Pharisees.

see https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/16782/22319 or any of the other top answers

Matthew 5:17 is... relevant. That said, there's a difference between Scriptural Judaism and what the people of the time were actually doing, but most people would still call the former "Judaism".

It is extremely likely that Jesus practiced Judaism. Note that "practiced" a religion means to do the things associated with that religion. You note most of the things yourself. Jesus attended services at the synagogue, he attended the festivals. He appeared to be a normal part of Jewish life. The Gospels were written by Jews and in a Jewish culture. It is extremely likely that they would have commented on place where Jesus did not follow Jewish practice.
Jesus' followers were Jews, and were expecting  Jewish Messiah. A Messiah who was openly disregarding Jewish laws and customs would not have been acceptable. After Jesus death many continued to follow Jewish practice, and it was a controversial matter to abandon that practice. It would have been much less controversial if Jesus himself had not followed in the main.
The Pharisees according to the Gospels spent a lot of effort in finding cases where Jesus had sinned. They objected to his healing on the Sabbath. If Jesus had been flouting the basics of Jewish law then they would have easily been able to establish this, and would not have needed to go to the lengths they did.
Jesus disagreed with the leaders of his time about correct Jewish practice, but those leaders also disagreed with each other on some matters. They would not have considered that the other parties were "not practicing Judaism". If we did see fundamental differences in the understanding of correct Judaism, Jesus' interpretation would be by definition correct (given that he is God) and Jesus would thus be practising "correct" Judaism.
It's important to remember that up until Jesus' dispensation from following the Law, practicing Judaism was the command of God and the right thing to do.
To answer your specific questions:

"Is/was it the "practice of Judaism" to publicly claim you are a special anointed Prophet?" Yes, if you are a special anointed prophet. Lots of prophets did it in the Old Testament.


"...to quote the Jewish prophets out of context?" Context is an elusive thing. Quoting like you describe would have been perfectly normal in that time.
"...to praise Gentiles in Lebanon and Syria". There is nothing wrong with saying good things about non-Jews when they deserve it.


"...to make the Jewish congregation so angry to throw you off a cliff?" Plenty of prophets attracted the wrath of Jews, especially when those Jews were being told an uncomfortable truth. Lots of prophets were stoned by the people they came to prophecy to. Jesus came to bring a fundamental change, and not everybody liked it.

It's not clear what your problem with the Isaiah passage is. Jesus does teach the same thing as Isaiah does according to that passage. He is specifically claiming that all the things in the passage he quotes refer to himself. By implication he is claiming the things in the passage around as well. However books in the Old Testament were not marked up into paragraphs, so it is often hard to tell where one "passage" ends and another begins. The parts you quote may be from an entirely different prophecy. Or not. If you are thinking that the things prophecied by Isaiah have not happened, it's important to realise that Jesus' works are not yet finished. He tells of his return in the future, when he will in fact rebuild ancient ruins and stop enemies from stealing Israel's food.
